# How to select an option in dropdown using selenium in java which has span html

Tags: java, selenium

Here is the HTML of the 3 options which are in span. How to I write to select either one of the options.

```
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-selBrand-container" title="Select a option" style="">Select a brand</span>

<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-selBrand-container" title="Option 1" style="">Option 1</span>

<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-selBrand-container" title="Option 2" style="">Option 2</span>
```

Comment: Please tell what you have tried so far and what are the problems you're facing

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem sometime back and had a hack for it. Not sure if it is the most elegant way to do it and if it works in your case as well (for me, I always needed to select the 2nd value in drop-down).

```
iWebDriver.findElement(By.id(<dropdown_id>)).click();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            Actions actions = new Actions(iWebDriver);
            actions.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).build().perform();//press down arrow key
            actions.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();//press enter
        }
```

`iWebDriver` is the WebDriver instance

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they all have different titles. You could use those to select which you want to click.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@title="Option 1"]')).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of the following :

```
List<WebElement> options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='select2-selection__rendered']"));

options.get(index).click();
```

---

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Option 1']")).click();
```